# ngrxOnRunEffects method stop efects dispatch other effects

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

### What I do

I have an Angular Application, and I am implementing NGRX 10 to manage account info after login.
So I did actions for login that calls when user do login or when load the app and have and session loaded from server.

This is how I implements my login Effect

```
  LogIn$ = createEffect(
    () => this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(UserActions.logInUser),
      switchMap(( action ) => {
        console.log('login');
        return this.backendService.login(action.credentials, action.remember).pipe(
          mergeMap(data => [
            UserActions.logInUserSuccess(data),
            UserActions.saveOAuthInCookie(data)
          ]),
          catchError( error => of(UserActions.loginUserFail(error)))
        );
      })
    ), { dispatch: true }
  );
```

I need to be sure that account info is already loaded from server when I access to restricted section of the page with a session previously open.

Then I try to implement something like the following code in my app module:

```
export function initApplication(store: Store<IState>): Function {
    return () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        store.dispatch(StartAppInitializer({}));
        store.dispatch(loadOAuthFromCookie({}));
        store.select((state) => state.user)
          .pipe(
            filter(user => ((user.oAuthToken && user.oAuthToken.length > 0 &&
              (user.account && user.account.email && user.account.email.length > 0) ) ||
              (!user.oAuthToken || user.oAuthToken.length === 0))),
            take(1)
       ).subscribe((account) => {
           store.dispatch(FinishAppInitializer({}));
           resolve(false);
       });
  });
}
```

and in my effects class implements `OnRunEffects` and this code:

```
  ngrxOnRunEffects(resolvedEffects$: Observable<EffectNotification>): Observable<EffectNotification> {
      return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType('LOGGED_IN'),
        exhaustMap(() =>
          resolvedEffects$.pipe(
            takeUntil(this.actions$.pipe(ofType('LOGGED_OUT')))
          )
        )
      );
    }
```

This changes it suppose to wait until the app call `FinishAppInitializer`.

### What I want

I want to stop the application loading until NGRX gets the account information from the server

### What I get

Before I implements ngrxOnRunEffects on my effects class, the effects I have works, but after I implements ngrxOnRunEffects on my effects class, the other effects stop dispatch other actions.

This are some image to reference whats happens when I do Login:

[Image Before I implements ngrxOnRunEffects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dDvX.png)

[Image After I implements ngrxOnRunEffects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chhdS.png)

### The solution I found

First I changed this:

```
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: () => initApplication,
      multi: true,
      deps: [[new Inject(Store)]]
    },
```

For this:

```
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initApplication,
      multi: true,
      deps: [[new Inject(Store)]]
    },
```

This change causes the application to stop until the promise is fulfilled.

And second, I moved the ngrxOnRunEffects method to another class, this solved the problem that no other effects were being called.